# Crystal report loaded with messy content in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: crystal-reports

I am facing a problem with crystal report that it is not loading properly in mozilla firefox. It is loading well in other browsers like chrome and IE.

The content of report are bit messy and also unable to see crystal report toolbar. Can anyone please tell me is there any settings or something which i need to do on server as the report works fine on local machine.

My problem is something similar to:

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/963126

I hope all understand my issue.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It might be useful to have screenshots to see the problem - words can only do so much.

Comment: Images you can see on the link, i have provided.. there uploaded two images, one with proper content and another with messy..

Comment: Which version of Crystal Reports are you using?